# Opayo Server API duplicate Acknowledgement being received

Tags: c#, opayo

I have a strange problem using Opayo API Server that I'm interested to know if anyone else has experienced.
I have got the integration working correctly in my production environment and a basket is being successfully bought multiple times daily.

However, I have noticed that the final confirmation call back response from Sage to finalize the transaction is calling my site multiple times for some users.

I have called Sage posting an acknowledgementStatus of OK and passing a redirectionURL.

It is this redirectionURL that seems to be called more than once but only for some transactions.

This is causing me a headache in my code because obviously, my code knows the transaction has already been completed and it is then erroring trying to figure out what to do with this orphaned request.

Has anyone experienced anything similar and have any suggestions?  I have numerous requests for help logged with opayo support but never seem to get any response.

thanks

Comment: Yes me too the same issue. I receive post twice sometime.

Comment: Did you find the cause for that?

Comment: I believe it wasn't a Sage issue in the end but users being able to refresh the confirmation screen when the response returned.  By blocking this option the error has gone away